# AngularJS - Processing asynchronous data in service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get some asynchronous data in service, which needs to further processed there. The code is here at [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6SkzXK?p=preview),

I simulate an async call with timeout, and once the data is received, the UI is updated.
But, I also need to process the data in service (doubleData) and later use in my UI. Say, I need to augment the data with some specifics.

Since, data is null when `{{doubleData()}}` is called, it never populates it. How can I achieve a way to process data further in my service(which is populated async - say $http)?

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp"> 
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../angular-1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            {{data}}<br>
            {{doubleData()}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### script.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.factory('myService', function($timeout) {
  var data = [],
      doubleData = [];

  var myService = {};
  myService.async = function() {
    $timeout(function(){
        data.length = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            data.push({val: Math.random()});                        
        }
    }, 5000); 
  };
  myService.data = function() { return data; };
  myService.doubleData = function() { 
    doubleData = []
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        doubleData.push({val: 10* data[i]});   
    };    
    return doubleData;                 
  };

  return myService;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function( myService,$scope) {
  myService.async();
  $scope.data = myService.data();
  $scope.doubleData = myService.doubleData;

});
```

### Output (after 5 sec):

```
[{"val":0.4908415926620364},{"val":0.25592787051573396},{"val":0.8326190037187189},{"val":0.6478461190126836},{"val":0.8502937415614724},{"val":0.19280604855157435},{"val":0.06115643493831158},{"val":0.5100495833903551},{"val":0.4134843284264207},{"val":0.5548313041217625}]
[{"val":null},{"val":null},{"val":null},{"val":null},{"val":null},{"val":null},{"val":null},{"val":null},{"val":null},{"val":null}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your issue is a typo in your for loop you need to access `data[i].val`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    doubleData.push({val: 10* data[i].val});   
};
```

Another way to do this (without watching for changes to variables) would be to bind `doubleData` the same way you are binding to `data` and call a function in your async callback to empty and populate `doubleData` with the calculated value. See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XLBYXO?p=preview) for an example.

Comment: Gloopy, I modified the plnkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/RbzODj?p=preview) to use $http instead of timeout. I am not sure plnkr allow to serve ajax request, hence I tested locally. The data is not displayed in this case. I can open another SO qn if you prefer. thanks

Comment: New question added, to followup above issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/angularjs-processing-http-response-in-service