# don't want to expose $http in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/angularjs-processing-http-response-in-service) about processing $http in a service, but I wanted to elaborate slightly. I would like my controller to be able to execute service calls using API similar to the Angular $http API:

```
$scope.login = function(user) {
  securityService.login(user).success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
  }).error(function(data) {
    $scope.error = data;
  });
};
```

That's a nice readable API. On the surface, all I would need to do in the service API is:

```
return {
  name : 'User Service',
  login : function(user) {
    return $http.post("/api/login", user);
  }
};
```

Great, it returns the promise and the `success` and `error` messages come with. But... What if I want to deal with the success and failure cases in the service? I want to maintain the nice, readable service API. In this case, maybe I'd want to preserve the user so that I could expose methods like `securityService.currentUser()` or `securityService.isLoggedIn()'.

I tried the `$http.post().then(...)` promise API, but those return the entire HTTP response. Again, I want to isolate HTTP to the services and maintain a similar concrete callback API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make your own promise in `login` using angular's `$q`:

```
var deferred = $q.defer(), 
    promise = deferred.promise;

$http.post("/api/login", user).success(...).error(...)

return promise;
```

Within the success/failure of the $http promise in your service, resolve/reject your deferred object.

**Edit:**

Expanding upon the `$http.post`:

```
$http.post("/api/login", user).success(function(data) {
  if (data == "foo") { // success case?
    deferred.resolve('you logged in!');
  } else {
    deferred.reject('something really bad happened!');
  }
})
```

Comment: can you expand your example?

Comment: sure, sorry, should have included that in the first example.

Comment: and then I just use success and error in the controller and get the text in each case?

Comment: Yeah, you could hide some of the complexity of the http response that way.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a test case and it seems that if I return the promise from the service API like this:

```
return $http.post("/api/login", user).success(...).error(...)
```

I can also do the same in the controller:

```
service.login(user).success(...).error(...)
```

and both get called, the service first and the controller second. That's perfect!

Comment: Sure, promises can be chained. You'd want to make your own promise if you didn't want to expose your controller to the low-level details of what `$http` was returning, and instead return something cleaner from your API.

Comment: One note to this: don't forget that `.success().error()` syntax is not supported by `$q`, and is emulated by `$http` (you can look at source code how promise is been extended). That means, that `$q` chaning feature can not work if you return promise form succcess/error's callbacks. I would suggest using `then(successCb, errorCb)` syntax - then you can return other promises from callback and get a quite fancy chainable workflow.