# Write to chosen scope variable with a service method

Tags: angularjs

If 'User' is a service and 'User.get' is a method that doing a request.

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="User.get(users,'id,uname,email,pw')">
<p>{{users}}</p>
```

How do I assign the request data to the scope variable 'users' with that code example?
I like that code style but I do not know how to implement it. Any ideas?

example on the service provider:

```
angular.module('User',[]).
provider('User', function() {
    var path = 'user.php';
    this.$get = function($http) {
        var r = {};
        r.get = function(variable,fields){
            $http.get(path+'?fields='+fields).
            success(function(data){
                //variable = data;
            });
        }
        return r;
    };
    this.setPath = function(p){path = p;};
});
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12513509/215945  Have your ng-click() call the async() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a controller and write the handler for the `ng-click` inside it. Here's an example:

Controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope) { 
    $scope.getUsers = function (fields) {
        $scope.users = User.get(fields);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="getUsers('id,uname,email,pw')">
    <p>{{users}}</p>
</div>
```

Another way to do it is to pass the `this` reference (scope) and the property name ('users') into the service:

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="User.get(this, 'users', 'id,uname,email,pw')">
```

And then on the `User` service, after getting the result, do something like this:

```
r.get = function(scope, prop, fields){
        $http.get(path+'?fields='+fields).
        success(function(data){
            scope[prop] = data;
        });
}
```

where `scope` = *this* and `prop` = 'users'.

IMHO, the first approach is the best one, the second one sounds a little hacky.

Comment: I did some improvement on your example and its posseble to just call User.get('users','id,uname,email,pw') without 'this'. But instead set the 'User.scope = $scope;' in the controller and 'r.scope[prop] = data;' in the callback function, then I dont have to worry about adding a argument for 'this' all the time :)

Comment: @Jossi be careful with those asynchronous requests, if you change the `User.scope` while an API request is being processed on the server you will end up adding the result to the wrong scope. This means that using `User.get()` in more than 1 place can be problematic.