# Execute code after multiple resources have loaded in Angular

Tags: angularjs

In Angular, what is the best practice for triggering code after multiple models have been populated by resource services. Nest $scope.$watch?

Right now, I'm cheating and checking off values in an array, which doesn't feel very "angular."

```
$scope.loaded = [];
$scope.modelA = aResource.query({}, function() {$scope.loaded.push('a')});
$scope.modelB = bResource.query({}, function() {$scope.loaded.push('b')});

$scope.$watch(loaded.length, function(newValue) {
    if ($scope.loaded.indexOf(modelA) != -1 && $scope.loaded.indexOf(modelB) != -1) {
        console.log('done!'); 
    } 
});
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/TizlifUL7FU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Angular routing, this is normally accomplished with the `resolve` parameter of the [when()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider#when) method.  See also [Delaying AngularJS route change until model loaded to prevent flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972026/delaying-angularjs-route-change-until-model-loaded-to-prevent-flicker)

If you don't want to delay your route change until the data is loaded, you can set up your own promises using $q.  Use $q.all() to wait for all promises to resolve.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15117739/215945 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/14545803/215945