# Returning response data from HTTP in Angular factory

Tags: angularjs, factory

```
.factory('Api', function($http) {
         var API = "http://127.0.0.1:4567/";
         return {
             get: function(method) {
                 return $http.get(API + method).success(function(result) {
                     return result;
                 });
             }
         }
     }
```

Then

```
console.log(Api.get("MAppData"));
```

Returns

```
Object {then: function, success: function, error: function}
```

Why does it not return the result (response data)?

Comment: i believe it is returning a promise, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/angularjs-processing-http-response-in-service

Comment: It might be possible, that it returns some error and you are not catching it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$http` returns a promise and you need to chain `.then()` to get the data like this:

```
Api.get("MAppData").then(function(response){
    var data = response.data;
});
```

Comment: What if I just want to return the response data instead and not the whole $http object? Or is this against best practice? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @subzero You can switch to use `$resource`, then you should be able to return the `$resouce` object which is a wrapper of promise and then angularjs  can binds it automatically to the view.