# Angularjs: ajax results are not loaded in controller

Tags: json, angularjs

**Scenario:**
i have created a document service that get all documents on load from json file

```
myModule.factory('DocumentService', ['$http', '$resource', function ($http,$resource) {

var docArray = [];        
$http.get('/Scripts/json/documents.json').then(function (response) {
    docArray = response.data;
});

_getDocuments = function () {      
     return docArray;      
}
return {
    getDocuments: _getDocuments        
}
}]);
```

i have created a Document controller that get values from document service

```
myModule.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'DocumentService','$http', function ($scope, docservice, $http) {

$scope.documents = docservice.getDocuments();
}]);
```

and in html

```
<div class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12 padding-rm-bs" data-toggle="button" ng-repeat="document in documents" ng-click="changePrimaryRightPanel(document)">
            <div class="col-xs-10 ">
                <ul class="list-inline pull-left">
                    <li>
                        <span ng-show="document.hide==true" >{{document.id}}</span>
                        <img ng-src="{{document.status |DocStatusFilter}}" width="12" height="16"></li>
                    <li>{{document.name}}</li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 ">
                <ul class="list-inline pull-right text-right">
                    <li>{{document.size | DocSizeFilter}} </li>
                    <li><span title="{{document.lastModified}}">{{document.lastModified}} </span> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Documents.json

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "status": 1,
            "name": "Draft Contract",
            "size": 2306867.2,
            "lastModified": "1-1-2013"
        }
    ]
```

**Issue**: 
$scope.documents doesnt get populated with result.

but if i make changes  in controller and move service functionality in controller then it works fine

```
$http.get('/Scripts/json/documents.json').
    then(function (response) {
        $scope.documents = response.data;
    });
```

how can i solve this issue. basically i wanted my document service to get , update , delete , add documents and want my controller just to call methods of document service

is this rite way of doing thing or i need to pollute my controllers with promises?

can some one guide me which is the best practice to handle factory and controller and their communication
any help will be appreciated

Comment: Everything works as it should work.

Comment: @TheHippo wat u mean by Everything works ?

Comment: The function you hand over to `then` in your service will be called long after your controller is initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your ajax request ends after you populate `$scope.documents`.

You should probably use promises following this snippet :

```
app.factory('myService', function($http) {
  var myService = {
    async: function() {
      // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
      var promise = $http.get('test.json').then(function (response) {
        // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
        console.log(response);
        // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
        return response.data;
      });
      // Return the promise to the controller
      return promise;
    }
  };
  return myService;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function( myService,$scope) {
  // Call the async method and then do stuff with what is returned inside our own then function
  myService.async().then(function(d) {
    $scope.data = d;
  });
});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12513509/1665540)

Comment: problem with this approach is i m handling services returned promises in Controllers. thats what i dont want basically wat i m looking for is to have a service that will have results of ajax calls and when i controller asks for data it gets data rather than a promise.

Comment: You could then initialize your  data inside a resolver but it wouldn't change the fact that you need to send a promise if you want it to work. It's the angular way, if it's not yours, go for backbone.