# Right way to work with two controllers at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a left sidebar in my webpage and his controller always working in the background. On the remaining side i have view of states that depends on the left side of the view (classic ui-view situation). I want to change variables in the sidebar's controller from the other controller. both active on the same time.
I don't want to use `$rootScope`.

What is the best way to implement that?

Comment: Maybe the best way is to init the vars in a directive and share them between the controllers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relation between two controller in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959553/relation-between-two-controller-in-angular)

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız One your link, the accepted answer use $scope events. It would be better to store it into a service. See [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43783633/4927984).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way is to use a [**`service`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) in order to share data/functions between controllers.

In the following example, changing the data in the `MainCtrl` also update the `SidebarCtrl`:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Data', function() {
    return { FirstName: '' };
});

myApp.controller('SidebarCtrl', function($scope, Data) {
    $scope.Data = Data;
});

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Data) {
    $scope.Data = Data;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="SidebarCtrl">
        <h4>SidebarCtrl</h4>
        Data is: <strong>{{Data.FirstName}}</strong>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
         <h4>MainCtrl</h4>
        <input type="text" ng-model="Data.FirstName">
        Data is: {{Data.FirstName}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u very much, that's exactly what I was looking for, well almost. I showing a table at my MainCtrl and after deleting,edding and adding some row i call the server to get the new table, and i want to see the changes also on the SideBarCtrl.

Answer (score 0):

### 1st way: use services

Services are singletons and you can pass data through services. For example, let's call our service `dataservice`:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('FirstController', ['dataservice']);

function FirstController(dataservice) {
  dataservice.dataToPass = 'data to pass through controllers';
}
```

And you can get this data from second controller like this:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('SecondController', ['dataservice']);

function SecondController(dataservice) {
  let dataFromFirstController = dataservice.dataToPass;
}
```

### 2nd way: use $emit/$broadcast (only if controllers are the parent and the child)

You can pass data **up** via `$emit` or **down** via `$broadcast` ($emit and $broadcast works similar, I'll show the example only with $broadcast). If `FirstController` is the parent and `SecondController` is the child, you can pass data through them like this:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('FirstController', ['$scope']);

function FirstController($scope) {
  $scope.$broadcast('passDataFromParentToChild', 'Data from FirstController');
}
```

And get data in `SecondController`:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('SecondController', ['$scope']);

function SecondController($scope) {
  $scope.$on('passDataFromParentToChild', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data); // will be "Data from FirstController"
  });
}
```

### 3rd way: use $scope.$parent (only if controllers are the parent and the child)

If you want to change variable of parent controller from the child controller, here is the easiest way (let's assume that `FirstController` is the parent of `SecondController`):

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('FirstController', ['$scope']);

function FirstController($scope) {
  $scope.varFromParentController = 'First';
}
```

Let's change `$scope.varFromParentController` from `SecondController`:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('SecondController', ['$scope']);

function SecondController($scope) {
  $scope.$parent.varFromParentController = 'Second';
}
```

Comment: @Trying_To_Know, if you want to take advantages of `$scope`, sometimes using `$scope` is better than `var vm = this` way