# Angularjs stubbed development - $http call along with $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I am doing stubbed development using angularjs. My stubs are JSON files on the server. So, I am making $http calls within the "stub" function to get the stubs. However as $http is asynchronous, the whenGET returns empty data all the time (it does not wait for http to complete). I looked into current questions on this subject. They provide approach to assign the return value of http call to a scope data model.  I want to return the data after the http request is complete. Below is the code.

```
stubbedOstnApp.run(['$httpBackend','$http',function($httpBackend, $http){
    var tempData;
    var get = function (){
        return $http.get('../test/data/program-categories.json').then(function(data){
            tempData = data.data;
            console.log(tempData);
            return tempData;
        })
    };
    get();
    console.log(tempData);

    $httpBackend.whenGET('lookup/program-categories').respond(tempData);
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^views\//).passThrough();
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\.\.\/test\/data\//).passThrough();
}]);
```

Basically, I want the line whenGET to wait until the tempData is populated. The tempData inside the get function is logged in the console after the whenGET method is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the tempData populated on the success callback you provide to $http.get

Try it this way:

```
 var get = function (){
    return $http.get('../test/data/program-categories.json').then(function(data){
        tempData = data.data;
        $httpBackend.whenGET('lookup/program-categories').respond(tempData);            
        console.log(tempData);
        return tempData;
    })
};
get();
console.log(tempData);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you should use promises: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Excellent explanation of promises here: [Processing $http response in service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/angularjs-processing-http-response-in-service)

Comment: My current code uses promises. I need something different. Most of the current solutions indicate how to populate a data model in $scpe. I want some of my instructions to wait until http is complete.