# AngularJS make REST call and display result in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I'm trying to get data from a REST service and display the elements in the browser.
Piece of code:

```
Server.prototype.typeNames = function() {
                var json = '{'
                        + '"query" : "MATCH n RETURN n.typeName LIMIT 10"'
                        + '}';
                $http.post("http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher", json).then(function(response) {
                    var data = response.data;
                    console.log(data);
                    return data;
                });
            }
```

I'm sure the JSON and the REST call are correct because I can see the data in my console and it's correct but I can't see it on the page.
I have also this in my js file:

```
$scope.typeNames = Server.typeNames()
```

In HTML:

```
{{typeNames}}
```

Also: I install AngularJS debug extension for chrome and there it's also null:

```
typeNames: null
```

Here (http://pastebin.com/itHv97da) you can find a bigger part of code. This code is not mine, the Server.prototype things were all there. I just added the Server.prototype.typeNames and I'm trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `typeNames` function isn't returning anything.

Depending on the version you can try returning the whole $http part, but even a better way would be to return a promise, and have the promise resolved within the `.then` callback.

Something like this:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http.post("http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher", json).then(function(response) {
    var data = response.data;
    console.log(data);
    deferred.resolve(data); // <--- this is the key
    return data;
});
return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: the `$http.post` isn't already a deferred objecT? why do we need to add another promise in the `then` then?

Comment: @PatrickFerreira I wasn't sure if it was so in every version (that's why I wrote that in my second sentence)... but even so, OP needs to return something from the `typeNames` function (`return $http.post...`) or just assign the response data to the scope variable, if it's the proper scope.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an async call you need to work with promises, some samples:

[Processing $http response in service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/angularjs-processing-http-response-in-service)

More info about how promises work:

http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Server.prototype.loadTypeNames = function(typeNames) {
  var json = {query : 'MATCH n RETURN n.typeName LIMIT 10'};

  $http.post("http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher", json).then(function(response) {
      typeNames = response
  });
}
```

in Your js file:

```
$scope.typeNames = [];
Server.loadTypeNames(typeNames);
```