# AngularJS HTML not updating after POST success

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to have an item in HTML update after a successful post query, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Here's the HTML side:

```
<div class='container' ng-controller='MainController as inputControl' >
    <div class='row well well-sm'>

         <div class='col-md-6'>

            <h2>Input Parameters</h2>

            <form name='addform'  ng-submit='inputControl.mainAddition()'>
                 <label>Number 1:</label>
                 <input ng-model='inputControl.inputData.num1' type="number" />
                     <br>
                 <label>Number 2:</label>
                 <input ng-model='inputControl.inputData.num2' type="number" />
                    <br>
                 <input type='submit' value='Add them!'/>
            </form>

         </div>

        <div class='col-md-6'>
            <h2>Result</h2>
            <P>{{inputControl.resultData}}</P>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the Angular side:

```
angular.module('pageLoader')
    .controller('MainController',['$scope', '$http',  function($scope, $http) {
       var controller = this;
       this.inputData = {};
        $scope.resultData = 0;

       this.mainAddition = (function() {
           console.log(this.inputData);
           $http({
               method: 'POST', 
               url: '/functions', 
               data: this.inputData
           })
           .success( function(data, status, headers, config){
               console.log(data);
               $scope.resultData= (data);
           });
           this.inputData = {};

       });
    }]);
```

The console log shows the correct response from the server, but the resultData in HTML isn't populating.

Edit:

Yeah, sorry, I totally mixed up $scope and this.  Find below working code

```
angular.module('pageLoader')
    .controller('MainController',['$scope', '$http',  function($scope, $http) {

       this.inputData = {};
       this.resultData = 0;

       this.mainAddition = (function() {
           var cntrlCache = this;
           console.log(this.inputData);
           $http({
               method: 'POST', 
               url: '/functions', 
               data: this.inputData
           })
           .success( function(data, status, headers, config){
               console.log(data);
               cntrlCache.resultData= data;
           });
           this.inputData = {};

       });
    }]);
```

Comment: Guess you are completely confused between assigning to scope and using controllerAs. Instead of setting it to scope set the data to `this.inputData.resultData`. But be aware you will have to cache `this` to another variable just before the callback. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) for more details.

Comment: Like @PSL said, if you are using `controller as`, inside your controller you should use `this` instead of `$scope`.

Comment: Never mind me, figured it out.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: when you are using controller as syntax you should remove $scope dependency from controller. Use "this.variable_to_be_shown" for all variables those are binded to view and use "var other_variable" for intermediate variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to correct your snippet is to change `$scope` to `controller` in

```
$scope.resultData= (data);
```

since you've already declared `var controller = this` in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Since the response is a html,you should use inject $sce service in the controller and do the following in the success method of the $http service

```
$scope.resultData = $sce.trustAsHtml(data)
```

Also its really a bad practice to have Async methods in the controller.Try to leverage angular services.

Please refer the [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/processing-http-response-in-service)