# angular material md-switch with array of objects

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Well, I'm making a switch using Angular Material switch, but it's not starting with its initial state as you can see on the picture. The label aside it is the value of it.

[image]

And as you can see, the switch starts deactivated from the beginning.

To Start, I'm getting the results from a get request, and putting it into an array.

```
$scope.questions = [];
```

The value I'm showing on the picture can be false or true.
On the `md-switch`, I've referenced directly to the property inside of the array.

```
<tr ng-repeat="quest in questions">
   <td><md-switch ng-model="quest.status">{{quest.status}}</md-switch></td>
</tr>
```

How can I set the value initially for the switch?

This is a Codepen with a test.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjzpNN

but this seems awkward tho. Doing my example it works fine, but with my development environment, it doesn't work.
This is the console.log of my array, I'm getting this as a get request using `$resource`.

Well, what is the problem?

Edit2:
Even more awkward, using the properties ng-true-value and ng-false-value the switch doesn't get the initial state.
[image]

Comment: Hi Matheus, could you provide an example, please ? JsFiddle/Codepen/etc.

Comment: For sure. Give me a minute.

Comment: Seems you solved your problem on your own :-)

Comment: @MichałDopieralski i've edited the question, an akward result =/. I had to answer the door. That delayed my answer.

Comment: Remember when things are coming back from the server that your controller/service/factory may load after the screen has rendered, so ensure you handle the return promise to load the data.

Comment: @StevenScott its been loaded successfully. The problem is, if i have the properties said in the md-switch, it doesnt get the initial state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated your JavaScript below, to use a service to get the results. However, I am just returning the hard coded data from your sample.  You should change the service to go and fetch your data. The service will be used as a promise, and will return when complete.

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('test', ['ngMaterial'])
    .service('testService', function() {
    // This should be modifed to then call your external API to get the data instead of hard coded results
        var questions = [
            { name : "teste",  status : true},
            { name : "teste2", status : false},
            { name : "teste3", status : true}
        ];
        return questions;    
    })
    .controller('testController', ['$scope', 'testService', function($scope, testService) {
        $scope.questions = [];

        $scope.questions = testService;     // Use service to get data, will update questions when promise returns.
    }]);
}())
```

There is no check on the data loading, so your screen will be empty until the service returns data.  However, when the service returns data, your view should be updated.

As your CodePen showed, you do not need the ng-true-value/ng-false-value, just the ng-model to list the field to get the setting from. The ng-true-value is the value to be set when you toggle the switch ([Angular md-switch docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSwitch) if you want something different from True/False (say A/B).

You might also need to use ng-disabled if you want to protect the switches from changing.

Comment: Can you use this service to return an http request?

Comment: Yes, the service would return your data from an http request.  The service would return the data and then the controller maps it into the fields for display on the page.  There are plenty of examples, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/processing-http-response-in-service.

Comment: So I am using a service inside of a controller but how would I make that service update data from a db?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385946/use-angularjs-mdswitch-directive-to-toggle-values-in-mysql

Comment: After you call the service and get the data, your controller sets the values from the service into the $scope.questions['teste'].status=$service.question.status.  This should be set by the service returning data, then you extract the result and assign it to your $scope variables in the controller.