# Angular setting variable as object through http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set a variable as the data object returned from a http request in angular, but the variable never sets to even if it is in the `$scope` unless it is nested within the success function. For example, if I do this in the controller :

```
    $scope.hello = [];
       var getAppointmentsurl = './dbscripts/getAppointments.php';

          $http({method: 'GET', url: getAppointmentsurl}).success(function(data) {

                $scope.hello = data;
          });

          console.log($scope.hello);

}
```

Hello is blank... so I set it up in services.js like this :

```
 this.getCalendarData=function(){
        var hello = [];
           var getAppointmentsurl = './dbscripts/getAppointments.php';

              $http({method: 'GET', url: getAppointmentsurl}).success(function(data) {

                    hello = data;
              });

              return hello;

    }
```

but still hello is blank. Am I missing something obvious?

edit --
[image]

Comment: try to put the console.log or the return inside the function and you ll see the your results

Comment: All the data is in 'data', thats coming through fine

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/processing-http-response-in-service). $http is async and you should apply different methodology to get result of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 this.getCalendarData=function(){
       var getAppointmentsurl = './dbscripts/getAppointments.php';

          return $http({method: 'GET', url: getAppointmentsurl}).success(function(data) {

                return data;
          });


}
```

This is asynchronus call we have to return data like above.

Comment: as http returns promise we have to resolve it in controller. as
getCalendarData().then(function(){
here will be your data
},function(error){
})

Comment: Beat me to it :) I would also recommend using the $q service and resolve/reject each response.

Comment: but what is an advantage

Comment: Just a personal preference, I often like to split up functionality upon a returned value. Perhaps overkill in this scenario, true.

Comment: Thanks for this @AkashBhandwalkar, i did what you said in services and added this to controller   AppStorage.getCalendarData().then(function(d){ 
    $scope.test = d;
 },function(error){ }); but still $scope.test and d are null

Comment: are you sure on you are getting data from service

Comment: Yeah i have added a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

As you put the api call as a method in the service, returning data from the service wont resolve yet, So in the controller the service return will only be a promise

```
serviceName.getCalendarData().then(function(data){

   //Success data
},function(){});
```

Service code must return like the below code and here you will get the entire response object,

```
return $http({method: 'GET', url:getAppointmentsurl});
```

One other way to get the data directly resolved stripping of the other properties is returning from service like this,

```
return $http({method: 'GET', url:getAppointmentsurl}).success(function(data){

    return data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Akash's correct answer, here's an example of how it should work.

In your view you should add logic to show the data only when hello exists. i.e. `ng-if="hello"`

controller:

```
ServiceName.getCalendarData().then(function(response) {
  $scope.hello = response;
});
```

service:

```
this.getCalendarData = function() {
  return $http.get('path/to/response/').success(function(data) {
    return data;
  });
}
```