# PushService.initPush.then is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to have a service return a promise, but keep getting `PushService.initPush.then is not a function`

Here is my service:

```
app.service('PushService', function($log, $q, $ionicPopup) {
return {        
    initPush: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        MFPPush.initialize (
            function(successResponse) {
                console.log("Successfully intialized push: " + successResponse);
                deferred.resolve();
            },
            function(failureResponse) {
                console.log("Failed to init push: " + JSON.stringify(failureResponse));
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        )
        return deferred;
    }
}
}
```

And my controller:

```
PushService.initPush.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
})
```

But am getting `PushService.initPush.then is not a function` why does this keep happening, to me it looks like I am returning a promise? I have been following this tutorial http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/ and looked at this SO question [Processing $http response in service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/processing-http-response-in-service) but cant get it to work.

Thanks for the help

Comment: First, it should be `PushService.initPush().then()`, as it's a function (and should be called). Second, the method itself should return `deferred.promise`, not just `deferred`.

Comment: Can't help but wonder what's `MFPPush.registerNotificationsCallback(notificationReceived)`. Its param isn't in the code shown, and it seems to be async as well. What happens if this call throws an exception?

Comment: @raina77ow sorry that doesnt matter forgot to take it out

Comment: @raina77ow thank you!! that fixed it, not sure how i missed that

Comment: Should I turn this into an answer?

Comment: @raina77ow if you would like to I will mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to call `initPush` method, not just access its property.

Second, in `$q` there's a not-so-subtle difference between `deferred` and `promise` APIs: the former is about modifying its state, and the second is about deciding what to do when it's settled (resolved or rejected). So you actually need to return `deferred.promise` (instead of `deferred`).

Finally, I'd recommend using $q constructor pattern instead, like shown [in the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#-q-constructor):

```
initPush: function() {
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    MFPPush.initialize(
      function(successResponse) {
        console.log("Successfully intialized push: " + successResponse);
        resolve(successResponse);
      },
      function(failureResponse) {
        console.log("Failed to init push: " + JSON.stringify(failureResponse));
        reject(failureResponse);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

As a matter of fact, if you don't need logging here, you can write it out as simple as ...

```
return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
  MFPPush.initialize(resolve, reject);
});
```