# get json object based on category

Tags: angularjs, json

i have json like this

```
[
  { 
    "id":1,
    "name": "BMW E46 PANDEM",
    "price": 130000,
    "curency":"USD",
    "color":"white",
    "category":"car"
  },
  { 
    "id":2,
    "name": "Yamaha",
    "price": 2000,
    "curency":"USD",
    "color":"white",
    "category":"Bike",
  },
  { 
    "id":3,
    "name": "Nissan GTR R34",
    "price": 130000,
    "curency":"USD",
    "color":"black",
    "category":"car"
  }
]
```

factory like this

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('ItemFactory', ['$http', function($http)
        {
            return {
               get: function() {
                return $http.get('scripts/item.json').then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
               }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

controller

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('apparelCtrl',['$scope','ItemFactory', function($scope,ItemFactory){
            $scope.title='car';
            ItemFactory.get().then(function(data) {
                $scope.apparelItems = data;
            });
            $scope.apparelItems=ItemFactory.get();
            console.log($scope.apparelItems);
        }]);
```

directive.js

```
angular
    .module('app.directives.gridViewApparel',[])
    .directive('gridApparel',function()
    {
        return{
            restrict:'E',
            scope:{
                data: '='
            },
            transclude:true,
            replace:true,
            templateUrl:"templates/directives/gridViewApparel.html",
            controller:function($scope){
                console.log($scope.data);
            }
        };
    }
);
```

diirective.html

```
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 ApparelThumbnail">
        <p class="title">{{data.name}}</p>
        <p>{{data.price}}{{curency}}</p>
        <a href="#/Apparel/{{data.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">detail</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

my car.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="carlItem in carItems | filter: {category:'car'}" class="">
        <grid-view-apparel data="carlItem"></grid-view-apparel>
    </div>  
</div>
```

both my car.html and bike.html got error

```
angular.js:14525 Error: [filter:notarray]
```

i try to add track by index before the filter but still got same error.
how to get the object from json based on category guys? 
thank you

Comment: the error is possibly caused by `grid-view-apparel`. maybe you can make some extra explaination about the directive `grid-view-apparel` you are using.

Comment: @Pengyy yes sir i will update my code

Comment: also post code of `gridViewApparel.html`.

Comment: `$scope.apparelItems=ItemFactory.get();` <- get rid of this line

Comment: @Phil oh its fixed. Thank you sir.whats wrong with that code. i thought i need to catch ItemFactory data

Comment: What you're doing there is assigning a `Promise` to `apparelItems` which is definitely **not** an array, hence the error `filter:notarray`. You're already calling `ItemFactory.get()` before that line which correctly sets `apparelItems` when it resolves so I'm not what you were thinking with that line.

Comment: i see, thank you for explanation

Answer (score 0):

The following code does not make any sense.

```
ItemFactory.get().then(function(data) {
    $scope.apparelItems = data;
});
$scope.apparelItems=ItemFactory.get();
```

Remove `$scope.apparelItems=ItemFactory.get();` from your code, as you are overriding the `$scope.apparelItems = data;` from before, thus the `$scope.apparelItems` equals to a promise, not to a result of that promise.

Answer (score 0):

Your return is problem. Analyse what your returning is it repnse.data or promise. Understand $http response. [Processing $http response in service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/processing-http-response-in-service)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil),

hes code fix the problem,

he suggested me to delete  `$scope.apparelItems=ItemFactory.get();` and now its fix