# why does my rest api call returns undefined response

Tags: java, angularjs, ajax, rest

I am trying to create a login page where the log in credential is checked in Backend and returns data... 
So I am using angular js for front end.

When I make a restful API call, it checks for the login credential but i am not getting the data back from the backend.

Ajax call to my API returns undefined so I am not able to display the response.data

Controller:
angular.module('myApp')

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, LoginService) {

    $scope.loginData = {};
    $scope.errors = [];
    this.msg={};
    $scope.login = function () {
    if ($scope.loginData != null) {
        console.log('Login Controller');
        console.log($scope.loginData);
        LoginService.Login($scope.loginData).then(function (response) {
            console.log('Login Controller2');
            $scope.showHide="IsVisible";
            $scope.msg=response.data;
            $location.path('signIn');              
            $scope.statuscode = response.status;
            console.log(response.status);
            console.log(response.headers);
            console.log(response.config);
            console.log(response.statusText);
            console.log(response.xhrStatus);
            //console.log(statuscode);
            //console.log(msg.message);
           console.log(response.data);
           var result = response.resource;        
          // result.$status = response.status;
         //  console.log(result.$status);


        }, function (reason) {
           // $scope.errors.push(reason.data.toString());
        });
```

Service:
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('LoginService', ['$http',  function ($http) {

```
    return {

        Login: function(loginData){
            console.log('Login Service');
            console.log(loginData.password);
            return $http.get('api/userlogin/checklogin', {params: {username: loginData.username, password:loginData.password}}) .then(testSuccess)
            .catch(testError);
            function testSuccess(response){
                console.log('Login Successful');
                console.log(response.data);
                return response.data;

                //console.log(response.data) this line prints data to console
             }

             function testError(error){
                return error;
             }

        },
```

How can I get the data from the server and display the data in html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Processing $http response in service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505760/processing-http-response-in-service)

Comment: Are you sure the request gets to the back-end? Maybe it doesn't get to the right endpoint (404 maybe?) or you're not sending a response correctly..
You should check the back-end's logs to see what happens, and use the Chrome Developer Tools to see if the request is sent correctly (and what response it gets (if any)).

Comment: Yes, the request hits the backend well. and for now I am just trying to return a string like successful or fail..But when i use chrome developer tool to see the response by using response.data..it says undefined there.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/checklogin", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public String checkname(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password )
   {
       System.out.print(username);
       System.out.print(password);
       if(username.equals("Test") && password.equals("123"))
       {
        System.out.print("Login Success");
        return "Login Success";
       }
       else 
       {
       System.out.print("Login Failed");
       return "Login Failed";
       }
       
   
        
   }

Comment: The code in comment above does not give us any understanding of what's going on on you back-end side, but there is nothing wrong with AngularJS code from your question, could you tell us what is in Chrome DevTools request `response` section?

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost:8080/api/userlogin/checklogin?password=123&username=Test
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 17:07:43 GMT
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __ngDebug=false
Host: localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Response Section:   Login Success                                                                                    It looks good in chrome DevTools request response section but somehow I am not able to get the data or status code in my view

Comment: I just realized that it works totally fine when I return an object from server but when I try to return String such as "Success " or "Fail", it shows bad data error